# joining 2 files on 2 columns but at different column numbers using awk

Tags: awk

I have 2 files which has to be joined on $1,$2 of 1st file and $1,$8 of 2nd file using awk.

file1:

```
111,123abc,eee,ttt,yyy
222,234bcd,ttt,yyy,333
```

file2:

111,hhhh,eeee,rere,,23,2014,123abc

222,jjkj,7878,uhjj,1,45,2013,234bcd

333,aaa,hhh,jjjj,2,78,590,567acd

output:

```
111,123abc,hhhh,eeee,rere,,23,2014
222,234bcd,jjkj,7878,uhjj,1,45,2013
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem a little? For example, do the two files have the same number of lines, with exactly one $1,$8 in file2 for every $1,$2 in file1? Or might there be multiple “111,…,123abc” lines in file2 (or multiple “111,123abc,…” lines in file1)? Might a $1 value (e.g., `111`) be paired with multiple $2 / $8 values (e.g., “111,123abc,…” and “111,123abe,…”), and vice versa? Are the input files in any particular order? Do you require the output to be in any particular order?

Comment: Your example is inconsistent. In the output, the second line has field 8 of file2 present as both field 2 and field 9, whereas the first line has only 8 fields.

Comment: Hi All,the question has been edited now. please share your answer as per the input and output.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]=1; next} ($1,$8) in a {print $1,$8,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' file1 file2
```

which gives:

```
111,123abc,hhh,eeee,rere,,23,2014,123abc
222,234bcd,jjkj,7878,uhjj,1,45,2013,234bcd
```

This isn't exactly the same as your output as you have 8 columns in the first and 9 in the second.  I've assumed that's a typo :-)

Comment: You’d get closer to the output the OP asked for if you said `{print $1,$8,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}` (maybe leaving off the second `,$8`). The example output doesn’t include *any* of the data from file1 other than the first two fields (i.e., the key fields): `eee,ttt,yyy` and `ttt,yyy,333` do not appear there.

Comment: @G-Man - so I would! I've fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Hey garthTheRed Thank you so much i got the desired output.Thanks for sharing the knowledge.Keep Rocking :)

Answer (score 1):

If the files are sorted on the join field (field #1) as shown in your example, then you could use the `join` command

```
join -t, -o 1.1,1.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8 file1 file2
```

Comment: You’d get closer to the output the OP asked for if you said `-o 1.1,1.2,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8` (adding `2.2` after `1.2`) and maybe leaving off the `,2.8`.